# How to select a uitableview cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController and i want to select the first row of the searchResultsController tableview on click of search button in the keyboard.
For that I tried implementing

```
-(void)searchButtonClicked:(UISerachBar*)searchBar {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  [self.searchResultsController.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:false scrollPostion:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
  [self.searchResultsController tableview:self.searchResultsController.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
 }
```

but it didn't work for me!!

Then I tried to make a separate method:

```
-(void) plotPinOnMapWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexpath;
```

and called it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and in `searchButtonClicked` method by passing the indexPaths.`But the problem is that the cell doesn't get highlighted the way it gets highlighted when user clicks on it.`

Comment: have you tried this  self.tableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView?

Comment: mine is a ViewController, not a TableViewController..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked!!

```
-(void)searchButtonClicked:(UISerachBar*)searchBar {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self tableview:self.searchResultsController.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, and is correct:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

optionally try this:

```
[self.tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

or you can use Segue to continue with result:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"showDetailView" sender:self];
```

In prepareForSegue method you pass parameters....